# sorting data in sqlite in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, sorting

How can I sort data in sqlite in c#? My code:

```
    static class Rank
    {
        private static SQLiteConnection _sqlite_conn;
        private static SQLiteCommand _sqlite_cmd;
        private static SQLiteDataReader _sqlite_datareader;
        static Rank()
        {
            // Create a new database connection
            _sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Highscores.sqlite;Version=3;");
        }

        public static void SortDataBase()
        {
            _sqlite_conn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM 'Highscores' order by 'Time'";
            _sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _sqlite_conn);
            _sqlite_conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

but this doesn't work. Could you help me ? Time is int value.

Comment: You don't need the ' before and after each attribute. Also what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want sort my table by Time value

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the data in the database table itself, but you can sort it when you select it. So for example `SELECT * FROM Highscores order by Time` should work but you have to actually execute your statement with `_sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader()` which returns a reader that can be used to iterate over the data. 
See this link: [SQLite Command](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand~ExecuteReader().html)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS,successfully sorted data based on the time in ascending order.

string selectsql = "SELECT filename,size,time FROM googledrive ORDER BY time ASC";